# How to increment all numeric values in the list except the first one

Tags: prolog

Write `increment_except_first` predicate to increment by 1 all numeric values except the first number in the list.

Here is my code, it is not working, but maybe someone can make it work

```
increase_tail_by_x([],x).
sum[H|T, x]:-sum(T,x),T=T+X.
```

Comment: If you want to learn to use Prolog (or need to learn it), then go back to the start of a tutorial and re-do the basics. That code has too many misunderstandings to answer without writing a tutorial on Prolog. `[H|T, x]` is not valid syntax (in SWI Prolog). `x` and `X` are different, read on atoms and variables. `T=T+X` is not addition and `5=5+1` doesn't make sense in a logic language because `5=6` isn't true. `sum` already exists and you are trying to overwrite it.

Comment: `increase_tail_by_x([],x).` has nowhere for the result after the increase, or it's not a good recursive base case. Same for `sum[` it has nowhere for the result and no recursive base case. At least skim-read the first 5 chapters of [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pageid=online)